# ServiceStack SSE plugin to handle response filter

Tags: servicestack, server-sent-events

Instead of using the ServerEventsFeature as a plugin for my service is there a way to send messages on a response filter?

How do I initial, connect and publish events? How should I handle the lifecycle of the SSE instance?

Answer (score 0):

No, any messages needs to be written to the Response that holds the SSE connection which are all managed by [ServerEventsFeature's IServerEvents](https://docs.servicestack.net/server-events#sending-server-events) dependency and is what is needed to be used to send messages to connected SSE clients.

Comment: Looking at this question now I think I can clarify what I am trying to accomplish. How do I use the  ServerEventsFeature outside of the ServiceStack Service. Resolve?

Comment: Yeah you can resolve `IServerEvents` from the IOC, e.g. `HostContext.Resolve<IServerEvents>()`